# Display image using a RSS feed

Tags: android

I have an application in which use a RSS feed reader. My problem is that I don't know what is the best way to display an image. The closer I could get was to pull the image description (). I know I could parse this String by myself and get the image url, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to solve this issue.  I tried using the SAX and the DOM classes, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to get the image URL from the XML RSS feed? There's nothing built into the SDK that's going to help you parse the XML, other than SAX or DOM which you have already noted. There is a learning curve to those, but they are reasonable approaches.

There's a project called [ROME](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javawsxml/Rome) that is an API for robustly parsing all sorts of feeds, including RSS. You could import this library into your android app. Note that this library has other dependencies, so you'd have to import them also. I haven't done it personally, but I have heard of people using ROME in Android apps, so it's doable.

Or more simply, if you just want the image URL and you don't need a complete feed parser, you can use `java.util.regex` to parse out the fields you want.

If you are asking how to display the image after you have the URL, kcoppock's answer explains it.

Comment: I was talking about the image's url. I don't know how to extract this information. Under the "description" tag my application receives the feed's description and image. The url is in this format <url width height>. I  could parse this string, but it would be better to have a method which returns the value of the src attribute. I hope this is clear. Thanks

Comment: there's nothing wrong with using regular expressions to parse bits out of XML strings. it's a quick and easy solution. if you need something more robust where you need to capture the structure of the XML document, SAX or DOM, or some API built on top of those is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to DISPLAY the image? I'm not sure if that's actually what you're asking, but just use an ImageView. Use an AsyncTask to download the image in the background, and then create a new Drawable from that downloaded image (might even want to cache it to storage) and set that as the source for the ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

there is a library for downloading and caching images in background from the URL
https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelperSample

=)